# ArangoDB waits infinitely after issuing start command by arangodb

Tags: arangodb

I am issuing the following command but the ArangoDB versio 3.11.8.1 instance hangs infinitely after printing the message of "Waiting for starter API to be available... component=arangodb" on the console.

```
sudo arangodb --starter.local --starter.host=0.0.0.0 --starter.port=8529 start &
```

What is the solution for this situation? The OS is Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

Please run only `arangodb --starter.local`.